# Ruby Google Drive API -- Unitialized Constant OOB_URI

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api, authorization

I am using the Google Drive API via the google-api-client ruby gem for a project, and I have some extracted code for authorization that looks like this:

**google_setup.rb**

```
client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file Rails.root.join('lib', 'assets', 'credentials.json').freeze
token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new file: 'token.yaml'
authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new client_id, Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE, token_store
user_id = 'default'
credentials = authorizer.get_credentials user_id
if credentials.nil?
  url = authorizer.get_authorization_url base_url: 'https://seeburg.herokuapp.com/'
  puts 'Open the following URL in the browser and enter the ' \
       "resulting code after authorization:\n" + url
  code = ENV["GOOGLE_CODE"]
  credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
    user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI
  )
end
drive_service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
drive_service.client_options.application_name = 'Seeburg Google Drive Integration'
drive_service.authorization = credentials
drive_service
```

In the 3rd line, notice `Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE`. That was originally `Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE_METADATA_READ_ONLY` and everything was working fine. When I change it to `AUTH_DRIVE` (so I can download files & not just get their names), I get the error `NameError (uninitialized constant GoogleSetup::OOB_URI)`.

I cannot find anything about this online. Please let me know if you know anything about this!

**token.yaml**

```
default: '{"client_id":"897908996328-12bdoukc29a5qvhffjpft18dkjtcgr60.apps.googleusercontent.com","access_token":"REDACTED","scope":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],"expiration_time_millis":1602463446000}'
```

---UPDATE----

When I add `OOB_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".freeze` to the top line, which I saw in the Ruby quickstart, it instructs me to open the URL, and then authorize the app, and then get the new code. I do that, I input the new code, and then it asks me to do it again in an infinite loop.

--- UPDATE 2.0 ---
Changing the perm levels in token.yaml stopped the error, but didn't solve the larger problem. I still can't download the files. Even though as far as I can tell, I should have the permissions to, `is_app_authorized` is still false. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct reason of your issue, for example, when you rename the existing file of `token.yaml` to others and reauthorize the scopes again, what result will you obtain?

Comment: I'm sorry, @Tanaike, I don't think I quite understand what you are saying. I added a little update with more info that may provide more context/answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. In your script, when you run the script, I thought that the file of `token.yaml` including the refresh token is created by authorizing the scopes. If my understanding is correct, when the file is renamed and the scopes are reauthorized again, what result will you obtain?

Comment: That's only when I create a new app. Not when I authorize. It no longer errors when I change the auth level in the token.yaml (changed my original Q to show this file), but now when I run it, even though I have AUTH that should allow me to download the files, I still can't. `is_app_authorized` still returns false

Comment: For example, create a new app through this page: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/ruby by clicking "Enable Drive API"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: No worries at all! Thank you for trying

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to study more in order to understand the various situations.

Comment: I followed the quickstart you linked, and before running it for the first time, I changed the scope, to `AUTH_DRIVE` and was able to create files and download no problem. My instinct is to ask similar questions to Tanaike - can't you just delete your token.yaml file and then run it again with the right scope? It should ask you to authorize the app with the renewed scope and create the token.yaml again. But maybe you have tried this. Also, is there a reason you are structuring your authorization differently from the quickstart?

Comment: Tried following the quickstart again & creating a new app, and I got this:

`Signet::AuthorizationError (Authorization failed.  Server message:)
{
  "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
`

It didn't give me a new token.yaml. How do I get that again? I get new credentials.json, but not a new token.yaml

Comment: Did you create a brand new project **from scratch** following the quickstart examples **exactly**? Because if you can't get that to authorize and get a token.yaml then you may have a completely new problem! My project has 4 files, credentials.json, quickstart.rb, test.txt (to create a pdf to upload), and token.yaml. If I delete token.yaml and run `ruby quickstart.rb` again, I get a link to authorize the app (like the first time), I go to the browser and get the code and paste it in terminal, and then it works.